# How to plot N vertical lines in a Ploty scatter plot using a loop?

Tags: python, plotly-python

I want to add **N** vertical lines to a scatter plot in Ploty.
My code works if I use this instruction repeatedly for every line: `fig.add_vline(x=lineN)` ,
but I don't want to add **N** instructions manually, so I'm trying by iterating over a list of my **N** lines. I don't get errors, however, I obtain the scatter without the vertical lines.

This is what my code looks like now (testing only with two lines):

```
line5=pd.to_datetime('2017-06-7 17:29:57')
line8=pd.to_datetime('2017-06-7 19:08:09')
list=[5,8] 
fig=px.scatter(df,x='time',y='height')
fig.update_layout(autosize=False,width=1100,height=400,)
for number in list:
    fig.add_vline(x="line%s" %number)
fig.show()
```

And this is how I expect the figure looks like:
[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `add_vline` wants a number as an input argument, but you provide a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- from your image, *xaxis* is **datetime**
- hence it's simple to add multiple lines as long as value you provide to **x** is of correct type
- code below simulates your dataframe and adds 20 randomly selected lines to figure

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": pd.date_range("6-Jul-2017", freq="90S", periods=1000),
        "height": np.sin(np.linspace(-np.pi * 2, np.pi * 2, 1000))*np.random.uniform(.9,1.1,1000),
    }
)
fig = px.scatter(df, x="time", y="height")

for t in df.sample(20)["time"].dt.to_pydatetime():
    fig.add_vline(x=t, line_width=2, line_dash="dash", line_color="red")
    

fig
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Rob Raymond ! You are right, x had a wrong type. Everything works now using this: line5=datetime(2017,6,7,17,29,57)
line8=datetime(2017,6,7,19,8,9)